# How to activate a pom.xml iff the os is not of a given family (eg. mac)?

Tags: java, macos, maven, pom.xml, tools.jar

From [Maven's website](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency):

```
    ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default-tools.jar</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>java.vendor</name>
          <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
          <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.2</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...
```

tools.jar is already inclduded on Macs, embedded with classes.jar. Was there no way to specify !mac in the activation settings (except for listing every os except the mac) in the pom.xml, instead of always getting:

```
ERROR>warning: [path] bad path element ""/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/lib/tools.jar"": no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '!' modifier in the os section of activation (tried and works with Maven 3.0.3).  Uses the same algorithm as the enforcer plugin, described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/rules/requireOS.html).

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>not-mac</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>!mac</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- Define non-mac properties here -->
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080437/jdk-tools-jar-as-maven-dependency) for a more complete description of using tools.jar in Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I found another method. Have the dependency in an "activeByDefault" profile. Have another profile (profile-2) which gets activated if the OS is mac. According to [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) the "activeByDefault" profiles get deactivated if any of the other profiles get activated. So if the OS is mac, profile-2 will get activated, which will deactivate the "activeByDefault" profile.

Comment: that won't do. The <os> property is not absent.

Comment: According to [this](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Activation-of-profile-based-on-property-equaling-a-value-td2262201.html) seems it will not work.