# maven: How to load tools.jar/classes.jar in an OS independent way?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, java

I am using a maven plugin that requires a class that is contained in the jdk's (windows) tools.jar (mac it's in classes.jar).

I add this as an explicit dependency of the plugin as follows:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>sun.jdk</groupId>
     <artifactId>classes</artifactId>
     <version>1.6.0</version>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</systemPath>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This works if I'm using OS X. However, it does not work if I'm developing on a Windows machine. Moreover, I dislike the use of ../Classes.

Is there perhaps a better way to load in the JDK provided classes?

**note:** I understand the default (Sun, now Oracle) is to ship the JDK with these classes in lib/tools.jar and that the only real outlier is those who develop using the repackaged Apple JDK. Be that as it may, I am still interested in a -system independent approach- that does not depend so much on the specific path.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080437/jdk-tools-jar-as-maven-dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining different build profiles for Windows VS Mac OS. 
See here for more details.
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: While this would work, I was hoping for something that wouldn't add yet another 40-50 lines to my pom.

Answer (score 0):

It will be interesting how to deal with it in git, because I share .idea dir.