# Problems with classpath with JSP using maven exec:java plugin under Windows

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, classpath, exec-maven-plugin

I'm trying to run a Jetty web framework from `main(...)` that loads a spring web context which loads JSPs at runtime.  This works great from the command line using `mvn exec:java` on OSX and Linux.  However on Windows, running Cygwin, I cannot get it to fully work.

The application loads and the web-context seems to build fine.  However when the first JSP page is rendered the JVM goes to compile it on the fly and throws the following error/exception:

```
org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.CompilerAdapterFactory.getCompiler(CompilerAdapterFactory.java:105) ~[gwt-dev-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:924) ~[gwt-dev-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757) ~[gwt-dev-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:382) [gwt-dev-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:472) [gwt-dev-2.5.1.jar:na]
    ...
```

I've done a ton of web searches and tried a number of things before posting.

1. The `JAVA_HOME` variable *is* set correctly.
2. I've made sure that it is pointing at the JDK and *not* the JRE.  The `tools.jar` file does exist under `%JAVA_HOME%/lib/tools.jar`.
3. The `JAVA_HOME` path is in `Program Files` and I was worried about the space but replacing it with `Progra~1` does not seem to work either.
4. We've tried both the `mvn` shell script under Cygwin as well as the `mvn.bat` script under DOS but both fail similarly.

Anyone else had this problem?  Do I need to change the `classpath` to specifically add a dependency to the `tools.jar` somehow?  Maybe something added to the `pom.xml`?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of maven are you working with? Have you looked into the source code of [ant](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.ant/com.springsource.org.apache.tools.ant/1.8.1/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/compilers/CompilerAdapterFactory.java#CompilerAdapterFactory.getCompiler%28java.lang.String%2Corg.apache.tools.ant.Task%29)?

Comment: I'm using maven 2.2.1 and I'm not using ant @SotiriosDelimanolis.

Comment: Whatever is producing your log seems to be using ant, I just assumed it was maven. With an older version, is it possible that there's no support for a Java 7 (if that's what you are using) compiler.

Comment: Duh, right.  I wonder if I'm pulling some crap from gwt-dev that I shouldn't be @SotiriosDelimanolis.  Thanks for poking me to actually look at all of the paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.

I'm not sure this is the right solution but I found a workaround from this answer:

> [Using javah maven-antrun-plugin with jdk 1.7, classes.jar became tools.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289700/using-javah-maven-antrun-plugin-with-jdk-1-7-classes-jar-became-tools-jar?lq=1)

I also utilized this answer: [JDK tools.jar as maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080437/jdk-tools-jar-as-maven-dependency)

I ended up adding a specific dependency for Windows in the pom which added the `tools.jar` specifically to the classpath:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>windows</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This adds a dependency only if the OS family is `windows`.  The system-path `../` is necessary in the path because `${java.home}` ends up as `$JAVA_HOME/jre` for some reason.  The `version` didn't seem to matter since 1.7 and 1.6 seemed to work.

Hope this helps other folks.