# How do I include tools.jar in my dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

[This reference](https://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency) explained how to include `tools.jar` in the dependencies.
But I don't know where should I insert that code to?
Should I insert it to the `setting.xml` of Maven or the `pom.xml` of my Java project?

I used the default maven in Eclipse 4.5.2(Mars.2 Release in Win7).
I want to include `tools.jar` in my project.
I could use the following code to include it in the `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
    <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I **also** want to try to use `java.home`, not `JAVA_HOME`.
I only know that they are different, but I don't exactly know the differences between them.

After reading that reference, I want to try it out. But I failed.
So how should I use `java.home` to configure the `pom.xml` file to include `tools.jar`?

**UPDATE:**

I could reference `java.home` like this:

```
<project ...>

...

    <properties>
        <java.home>D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45</java.home>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Note that Java 9 will not have tools.jar anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240134/declare-maven-dependency-on-tools-jar-to-work-on-jdk-9

Answer (score 2):

You can define a similar `profile` in your `pom.xml` as -

```
<!--This can help you use a custom java home path-->
<properties>
  <java.home>/your/path/to/java</java.home>
</properties>

...

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>default-tools.jar</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>java.vendor</name>
        <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/relative/path/to/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</profile>
```

Using the [reference mentioned](https://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency) to form the profile above.

You need to specify the path to your custom Java home under the `properties` which can further replace it in the `systemPath` under the dependency where you specify further the relative path to the `tools.jar`.

Comment: You mean I have to define `java.home` in the `properties` first, then I can use it in the `systemPath`. Otherwise, maven doesn't know what `java.home` is.

Comment: No. I meant just in case you want to specify a custom path that is not already set in your environment variables or bash_profile. The properties is more like a variable whose value we are trying to replace in  systemPath above.

Comment: I'm using Windows7. I have set JAVA_HOME in my environment variables. It's `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66`. I could use it. But I just want to know how to use `java.home` in the profile without explicitly specifying the value of `java.home`. And I don't know the value of `java.home` in the profile.All I know is that in the java application the value of `System.getProperty("java.home")` is `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre`. I have two versions JDK installed in my machine.

Comment: You can whichever you want to use by specifying its path under the `java.home` properties in pom.xml. *If not* specified maven would use the one which is set in the Windows environment variables instead.

Answer (score 0):

@nullpointer is correct, just to add on the maven properties regarding your java home, you can see the output of the Maven java.home property as compared to your JAVA_HOME environment variable with running `mvn validate` and adding to your pom the code snippet below:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>Displaying value of java home property: ${java.home}</echo>
                                <echo>Displaying value of JAVA_HOME variable: ${env.JAVA_HOME}</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

For example, on my system it outputs (among other things):

```
 [echo] Displaying value of java home property: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
 [echo] Displaying value of JAVA_HOME variable: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: How many places where I can configure to affect the results of `java.home` and `JAVA_HOME` are there in my machine?