# Usage of tools.jar in JDK9 and beyond

Tags: java, java-9, java-11, tools.jar

IN my project, I have a dependency on tools.jar for instrumentation purposes. Without tools.jar in jdk9 and beyond (in JD11 too), where and how can I resolve the dependency?

Has anyone come across same scenario?

Regards,

Comment: what *certainly* matters is what you were using from that jar and does the JDK not expose those classes or API anymore? Do take a look at - [Declare maven dependency on tools.jar to work on JDK 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240134/declare-maven-dependency-on-tools-jar-to-work-on-jdk-9)

Comment: @Naman           the tools.jar has been totally thrashed into JDK's internal modules. In other words, any dependency on `tools.jar` needs to be revisited and refactored, for sure. My question is - is there an example of how this refactoring/change should be performed.

Comment: What means “dependency” to you? For Java code, you don’t need to do anything. Perhaps, you’re talking about a build environment that requires you to name “dependencies” explicitly (e.g. Maven). But you didn’t name one.